# Getting web page hit count with IIS logs in Azure

Tags: iis, logging, azure, hit-count

I have a website hosted in Azure as a cloud service (not as a website), and I need to get the hit count for every web page of the site.

I enabled Azure Diagnostics, and I see the IIS logs copied to my blob storage, however this logs contain very few data (only one hit to a javascript file).
Furthermore, putting "Verbose" or "All" in the diagnostics configuration of the web role doesn't seem to affect the results, I get only one line (an access to a css file, or an image file, etc).

I'm using Azure SDK 2.0.

Is it possible to use the included IIS logs generated by azure to get a hit count? What should I need to change in the diagnostics configuration?
Or should I need a different approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IIS logs it produces are the same ones you'd find on a Windows Server anywhere.  Note that depending on the settings you provided to the diagnostics it might take a little while before the data is moved to the storage account.  Setting the level of verbosity for the configuration determines what is moved from the instances over to the storage account.  Did you give it plenty of time to move the data over before looking at the file in storage again?  Sometimes it just brings over what it has, and of course, there could be buffering which means when the file was brought over not everything was in it, etc.

You should be able to get this information from the logs, and yes, you should be able to do it from the IIS logs.  That being said, if what you are after is a hits per page I would suggest actually a different approach.  Look at an analytics provider like Google Analytics or one of the competitors to that.  You'll get a massive amount of information beyond just page hits and no need to worry about parsing log files, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I gave it plenty of time (about 2 hours) and I only see one line with "Verbose" or "All", however, with "Error" I see more lines. The problem I saw was that the second time you enter the same page it is not logged (maybe because of the browser cache). I will try a different approach (I tried adding a custom HttpModule, and it seems to work great) so I can count every hit. I didn't want to use analytics because at first I wanted to stay out of third party libraries, but I will consider it in the future.